# How to prevent change background-color of button for G-Suite add-on on mousedown

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, gsuite-addons

I added button and change it background-color by `.setBackgroundColor()` function. But on mousedown button changes background-color to blue.

Default state:

[image: Default state]

After mousedown:

[image: After mousedown]

How I can prevent change background-color of button?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, there's no function that allows you to change or disable the default behavior on `mousedown` event for a [TextButton](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-button) object. I have tried setting the button with [setOpenLink](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-button#setopenlinkopenlink) and [setOnClickOpenLinkAction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/text-button#setonclickopenlinkactionaction) but the behavior is the same changing to the same blue color on `mousedown` event regardless of the color you set to the button with `setBackgroundColor` method.